# Facebook Posting Photo using App Access Token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Scenario:

- User has completed the OAuth process and has given our app publish_actions, publish_stream, user_friends, and user_photos permissions.
- While we have the user token from the user logging in, we have retrieved and persisted the user's Facebook id
- Also while we have the user token, we have created a photo album to later post photos to and persisted the Facebook album id
- NOTE: We have not persisted the user token for legacy reasons
- At a later time, we attempt to post a photo to the album previously created using the following code:

  ```
  FacebookClient client = null;
  Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null;
  string path;
  FacebookMediaObject media = null;

  client = new FacebookClient();
  client.AppId = "{our app id}";
  client.AppSecret = "{our app secret}";

  media = new FacebookMediaObject();
  media.ContentType = "image/jpg";
  media.FileName = "AnyAllContactTypesProblem.jpg";
  media.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\" + media.FileName));

  parameters = new Dictionary<string,object>();
  parameters.Add("name",
                "Test Image 1");
  parameters.Add("source",
                 media);

  path = "/" + "{album id}" + "/photos";

  dynamic result = client.Post(path,
                               parameters);
  ```

The POST operation results in the following exception:

```
   (OAuthException - #102) A user access token is required to request this resource.
```

The Facebook documentation indicates that an "app token" which is derived from the app id and app secret can be used as the access token for posting a photo on someone's behalf as long as publish_stream permission has been provided to the app which it has in our case.

Are we missing something needed in the code above or has Facebook changed the required permissions for posting photos?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from where did you read this-

> an "app token" which is derived from the app id and app secret can be used as the access token for posting a photo on someone's behalf as long as publish_stream permission has been provided to the app which it has in our case.

But this is **not** true. Once you got the `publish` permission, you can post the **stories/feeds** on the wall and get the basic info using the app access token. Posting the **photos** is not allowed! Here's what the documentation says-

> App access tokens can also be used to publish content to Facebook on behalf of a person who has granted an open graph publishing permission to your application. 
> [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)

One thing that you can do-

Save the extended token to your server (that expires in 60-days, after that user must go through the login again to get the new token), to get the extended token-

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Comment: I do have a link to the page where I got the "paraphrased" about the app token.  It may well have been information in the deprecated REST API which we are currently using with only the "app token" to upload photos.  Recently the photo uploads using the deprecated REST API has stopped working for photo uploads for some but not all users.  This is the primary reason we are changing to using the SDK/Graph API.  Do you know why the deprecated REST API approach has stopped working for some users?
Would adding "photo_upload" to the permission the user grants our application change anything?

Comment: Sorry but no idea on this one